# input type range

Tags: html, css

[image: input type range]

Здравствуйте,как стилизировать input type range,чтобы он стал таким?

Comment: Так это почти дефолтный бутстраповский `range`

Comment: облазил документацию bootstrap`а - не нашёл :(

Comment: немного наврал, посмотрите примеры для этой реализации как вариант http://seiyria.com/bootstrap-slider/

Comment: спасибо,только я немножко не понял,как подключить,там не описано

Comment: там на cdn есть ссылка https://cdnjs.com/libraries/bootstrap-slider

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Посмотрите в сторону ION Range Slider:

> http://ionden.com/a/plugins/ion.rangeSlider/index.html

Там достаточно понятная документация и поддержка скинов.

Comment: Есть плагин получше.. без jquery, с более мощным api:
https://refreshless.com/nouislider/